# How can I get a cell to equal another cell based of the condition of other cells?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Please look at the LINK provided at the bottom this is a spreadsheet.

I am trying to figure out the bills I need to pay. I am used to being paid every 2 weeks and I am on a new weekly schedule. I have decided to make a spreadsheet, to try to figure out which bills I have already transferred money for and which bills I still need to transfer money for.

Basically, I want the cell in F3 to = the F column + the cell to the left, unless the cell in F9 or F10 = d, then either add the F3 column + F9 + E3 (if F10=d) or add the F3 column + F10 +E3 (if F9=d) or add the F3 column + F9+F10 (if both =d).

[Link to Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r16gUzcJkwJ-gj1v3DDDijHVWjL47svnY5lQ-kPF9cE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: `cell in F3 to = the F column + the cell to the left` <-- isn't F3 itself is in F column ? we cannot put `=F3+E3` formula in `F3` cell right?

Comment: @p._phidot_ judging by his spreadsheet, the range `1:5` is frozen and will be formula only, so their 'active range', so to speak, would be starting at row 6.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. When you say `the cell to the left`, you mean to the left of `F3` or to the left of every other cell from `F6:F`?  And `F9` and `F10` only join the sum if they're `d`, otherwise they are left out?

Comment: @RodrigoBiffi To the left of `F3`. So it would be something like `=SUMIF(F6:F,"t",$B6:$B)+E3 [[unless F9 or F10 = 'd']  if F9='d' then add F10+E3, if F10='d' then add F9+E3, if F9 or F10 = 'd' do not add E3]`

Comment: @Zazz1772 you actually can't sum `F9` and `F10`, so I'm guessing you want to use their respective values on `B` column, right?

Comment: @RodrigoBiffi yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a [copy of your sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19P82h5SsoQbJsT66pr1O8YHxaonYk2kOQ-_krzT7jZo/edit?usp=sharing), and tried for a bit, and that's what i got:

`=IF(AND(F9="d",F10="d"),SUMIF(F6:F,"t",B6:B),IF(F9="d",SUMIF(F6:F,"t",B6:B)+E3-B9,IF(F10="d",SUMIF(F6:F,"t",B6:B)+E3-B10,SUMIF(F6:F,"t",B6:B)+E3)))`

There is probably a better way to solve this without this many `IF` statements, but I honestly can't help you there.

What it does is literally just check if both `F9` and `F10` are `d`, and do the sum without E3. If not, it checks only for `F9` leaving it out if so, then for `F10` doing the same, and at last just sums everything up if neither of them are `d`.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it would be a bunch of IFS, ORS, and/or ANDS. Just couldn't think of how to fit them together.